# For any set we can construct a vector space on it

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Can we construct a vector space on any finite set? It is clear, that on any finite set can be construct the transposition group $S_n$, where $n$ -- cardinal of elements of this set. I thought about non-zero characteristics fields, but I think that this is impossible, for ex. $\mathbb{F}_2$ -- $2$-elements field on $\{0,1\}$ and we will be have $Id_X = (1_{\mathbb{F}_2} + 1_{\mathbb{F}_2})*S_1 = S_1 \cdot S_1 \neq Id_X$, where $Id_X$ -- identity transposition and $S_1$ -- any another transposition, $\cdot$ -- composition between transpositions in $S_n$ and $+$ -- additive operation in field, $*$ -- multiplication on scalar.

So what after? How can I check zero characteristics fields?

And what about infinite sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  For instance, there can be no vector space structure on a set of order $6$.  No matter the ground field (and you only have two options here, $\mathbb{F}_2$ or $\mathbb{F}_3$) the arithmetic won't work out on the dimension to make the order of the underlying set $6$.  (It should be clear that a vector space $V$ of finite dimension $n$ over a finite field of order $q$ will have $|V|=q^n$.)

Comment: For now I think, that if we speaking about vec.space on a finite set $X$ with $n$ elements,  we should think about the space with $n$ vectors and the $Set$-functor image of this vec-space, that will be have $n$ elements in it. So if we have set of order 6, we should find 6 element-vec.space but the number of this elements in vec,space depends on the number of the field, bcs $|V| = q^m$, so $n = q^m$, where $q$-- order of field-set and $m$ -- dim of space. And after... Why $n = q^m$ is impossible?

Comment: How can you write $6$ as a power of prime?  (Finite fields themselves have order a power of a prime, so $V$ will as well.)

Comment: yes, okey) thx) perfect!


but what about infinite sets?

Comment: That's harder because of cardinality issues. For instance, if $V$ has cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$, then choose a bijection $V \to \mathbb{R}$ and pull the vector space structure on $\mathbb{R}$ back to $V$.

Comment: oh, nice, just copy structure... 

Thank you so much, you answered my questions)

Comment: Well, to be fair, I don't think I did.  You'd need someone who knows much more about cardinal/logical difficulties than I do.

Comment: I rather wanted to find out if there was such an opportunity: by showing an example, you showed what can be set on an infinite set. It is clear that, for example, if we consider a set of countable powers, we can copy the structure of rational numbers. But in the case of large cardinals, we simply do not have standard fields with multiple carriers of such a large structure.